# How do I subtract odd index values and add even index values in a list? (a-b+c-d+e)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given a list of integers, I want to subtract all the integers with an odd index and add all the integers with an even index. Is there any compressed way to do this without the regular "while loop with iterator and add/subtract"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use slicing with a step:

```
n = sum(L[0::2]) - sum(L[1::2])
```

The sequence slicing syntax `L[i:j:k]` is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations), specifically refer to the note 5.

Comment: Sorry - I'm new to python, but would it fail if I have an odd number of components?

Comment: `L[1::2]`, for example, is a slice containing the elements of L beginning at index one and then stepping through with a step size of 2, i.e. all the elements at odd-numbered indices. Similarly `L[0::2]` are the elements from even-numbered indices. I've added a docs link explaining this notation.